# How to get the response of an intermediate API call?

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am currently trying developing some API tests using rest-assured. More specifically, I am trying to test Stripe's payment gateway (3DS). The way it works is that I subscribe a user using our API endpoint, which has a response including an external link to Stripe's website where the user fills out a form for their payment details.

This part is fine and dandy.
The problem lies ahead. I need to be able to send a POST call to this form with the payload of the form. However, the POST payload that Stripe is expecting includes other elements that are not part of the form such as **muid, guid, sid, key, and payment-user-agent**. After doing some research, I see that these elements are given when the user first loads the form. However, they are given are given at an intermediate API call during the loading of the page. Meaning, if I try to call a GET on the form page, I will not retrieve these elements. The loading of the page calls other endpoints sequentially, where at some point, it makes a call to another endpoint with an encrypted request payload, which I cannot reproduce for my automated tests, which returns the muid, guid, and others.

I was wondering if it were possible to get the response of the intermediate API call somehow?

I tried doing research of methods that can possibly achieve this, but I have yet to come up with something that is API testing related.

I cannot do a Selenium script to push the form for me, as I need it to be API testing related, and with no GUI browser included.  I could potentially run Selenium in headless maybe, but I was wondering if there was anything more lightweight or a simple way to retrieve the response of the intermediate api call before I proceed with that solution.

Comment: Why cant you just get that uri that provides required data, parse it and then add to your POST request?

Comment: Because the URI that provides the required data has a needs payload that is different with every time we want to make a request and is encrypted, so the payload looks like a bunch of jibberish. And, unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to find any other intermediate call that gives that encrypted payload as a response.